# Passing a multi-line string as an argument to a script in Windows

Tags: python, windows, string, dos, batch-file

I have a simple python script like so:

```
import sys

lines = sys.argv[1]

for line in lines.splitlines():
    print line
```

I want to call it from the command line (or a .bat file) but the first argument may (and probably will) be a string with multiple lines in it. How does one do this?

Of course, this works:

```
import sys

lines = """This is a string
It has multiple lines
there are three total"""

for line in lines.splitlines():
    print line
```

But I need to be able to process an argument line-by-line.

EDIT: This is probably more of a Windows command-line problem than a Python problem.

EDIT 2: Thanks for all of the good suggestions. It doesn't look like it's possible. I can't use another shell because I'm actually trying to invoke the script from another program which seems to use the Windows command-line behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't understand - does what you have now not work?

Comment: You should split by "\n" and remove the "\r" beforehand for better platform compatibility. Does `bash` put carraige returns in it's arguments? (Not sure).

Comment: You shouldn't use the string module at all. That line should read `lines = multiline.splitlines()`

Comment: All good suggestions. My total experience with python amounts to about an hour so far.

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is pretty old, but I came across it while trying to solve a similar problem, and others might as well, so let me show you how I solved it.

This works at least on Windows XP Pro, with Zack's code in a file called
"C:\Scratch\test.py":

```
C:\Scratch>test.py "This is a string"^
More?
More? "It has multiple lines"^
More?
More? "There are three total"
This is a string
It has multiple lines
There are three total

C:\Scratch>
```

This is a little more readable than Romulo's solution above.

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose the argument in quotes:

```
$ python args.py "This is a string
> It has multiple lines
> there are three total"
This is a string
It has multiple lines
there are three total
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might work:

```
C:\> python something.py "This is a string^
More?
More? It has multiple lines^
More?
More? There are three total"
```

Comment: This lets me effectively span my string across multiple lines but still ends up without the "newline" characters in the string.

Comment: The empty lines are important in this case. At least it worked for echo to output multiple lines but I couldn't test here otherwise at the moment. If all else fails, use the pipeline solution others suggested. Passing multiple lines through stdin is no problem, at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing which worked for me:

```
C:\> python a.py This" "is" "a" "string^
More?
More? It" "has" "multiple" "lines^
More?
More? There" "are" "three" "total
```

For me [Johannes' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749049/passing-a-multi-line-string-as-an-argument-to-a-script-in-windows/749323#749323) invokes the python interpreter at the end of the first line, so I don't have the chance to pass additional lines.

But you said you are calling the python script from another process, not from the command line. Then why don't you use [dbr' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749049/passing-a-multi-line-string-as-an-argument-to-a-script-in-windows/749319#749319)? This worked for me as a Ruby script:

```
puts `python a.py "This is a string\nIt has multiple lines\nThere are three total"`
```

And in what language are you writing the program which calls the python script? The issue you have is with *argument passing*, not with the windows shell, not with Python...

Finally, as [mattkemp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749049/passing-a-multi-line-string-as-an-argument-to-a-script-in-windows/749329#749329) said, I also suggest you use the standard input to read your multi-line argument, avoiding command line magic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Windows command-line, but would the following work?

```
> python myscript.py "This is a string\nIt has multiple lines\there are three total"
```

..or..

```
> python myscript.py "This is a string\
It has [...]\
there are [...]"
```

If not, I would suggest installing Cygwin and using a sane shell!

Comment: Neither. First of all, cmd does not use \ as escape character, instead it uses ^. Secondly, ^n would just yield a literal n, since ^ can only be used to escape otherwise special characters but it has no capabilities of generating special chars, like \n, \r, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting you multiline text as a variable and then passing the expansion of that into your script. For example:

```
set Text="This is a string
It has multiple lines
there are three total"
python args.py %Text%
```

Alternatively, instead of reading an argument you could read from standard in.

```
import sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print line
```

On Linux you would pipe the multiline text to the standard input of args.py.

$ <command-that-produces-text> | python args.py

Comment: Does not seem to work at all. Not directly from the windows command line, and not from a batch file.