# windows cmd: how to pass an argument with a line break?

Tags: cmd, line-breaks

I'm trying to have sometings like

```
cmd> svn ci -m "argument"
```

And the "argument" I want to be a multiple-line text.

How can I do that?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/749049, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7041069, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433977

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `cmd`. The `-m` command line option only accepts a single line.

Comment: In linux I'm able to do something like
[code]svn ci -m "\
first line\
second line\
third line\
"[/code]
so that's not a -m's issue.

Ok, lets forget svn ci -m. 
How do I pass multple-line text to virtually any program in cmd?

Comment: `cmd` does not support multiline string literals.

Comment: Talking on svn particularly, there is a workaround.
Fortunately, an -F key allows to pass a name of file instead of typing the comment directly to the command line:

`svn ci -F notes.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I found [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/150120/282374) that might be interesting: you can escape the newline with `^`. (It seems you can't escape args inside quoted strings, but that might be OK because your example didn't need quotes?)

If I wanted to `echo`

```
ab
c
d
```

I'd type this

<kbd>e</kbd>
<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>h</kbd>
<kbd>o</kbd>
<kbd>SPACE</kbd>

<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>b</kbd>
<kbd>^</kbd>
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>^</kbd>
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

<kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Which looks like this:

```
>echo ab^
More?
More? c^
More?
More? d
ab
c
d
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's pretty cool. But unfortunately it doesn't work inside of an argument. I.e. you can't do something like `echo "ab^c"` - it will be printed as is.